# public s3 bucket file download getting access denied error for files transfered from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi i have created a bucket in s3 and made public, If i upload any file i am able to download the file with url from public. But when I did a copy of all s3 files from another account (which also had public permissions) to this new bucket in different account i am not able to downlaod those files in both public / logged in to same account

Note:

- there is no kms keys set as well i.e by default no encription in the source bucket,

When I Manually try to provide make public ACL then following error i am getting, even though I have a full administrator access . I am not able to dissable the ACL as well to convert the bucket owner to have full permssion and over there as well i am getting error.

```
You’ll need s3:getObjectACL permissions to make this object public from the S3 console.
```

Please help me how to fix or better approach to migrate the s3 files from one account public bucket to another account public files

Comment: Check to see who owns the object in the bucket (not the bucket itself). My guess is the files were copied to the bucket using credentials assigned to another account so the owner of the file is not the root of the account the S3 bucket resides in. This means the bucket policy won't or won't fully apply to the object. The best practice is now to disable ACLs on the bucket which eliminates a lot of the bucket policy vs object ACL confusion.